# BASH: is it possible to change a prompt of function based on its parameter?

Tags: bash, function, parameter

I want to construct a function that will change its user input prompt based on its parameter.

`my_fucntion` takes 1 parameter as `db_host` after prompting the user for input:

```
function provide_host () {
    echo "Enter NAME OR IP OF ${function_param1} DATBASE HOST: "
    read global function_param1_db_host
}
```

So if I call the function as

```
function provide_host (primary)
```

it should prompt as

```
echo "Enter NAME OR IP OF PRIMARY DATBASE HOST: "
```

but if I use

```
function provide_host (secondary)
```

it prompts

```
 "Enter NAME OR IP OF SECONDARY DATBASE HOST: "
```

My idea is that I have to use an `if` statement for that, but I'm not sure if I can use the function's parameter as a variable for promptin the user inside the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$1` to get the first parameter:

```
function provide_host () {
    echo "Enter NAME OR IP OF $1 DATBASE HOST: "
    read global function_param1_db_host
}
```

or to convert it to upper case:

```
function provide_host () {
    echo "Enter NAME OR IP OF ${1^^} DATBASE HOST: "
    read global function_param1_db_host
}
```

Then call your function with:

```
provide_host primary
provide_host secondary
```

---

However, I'd do it slightly differently.  Instead of trying to set a global variable, I'd prompt in stderr and return the IP from the function in stdout:

```
function provide_host() {
    read -p "Enter NAME OR IP OF ${1^^} DATABASE HOST: " host >&2
    printf "%s" "$host"
}

primary_db_host=$(provide_host primary)
secondary_db_host=$(provide_host secondary)
```

Comment: Redirecting the prompt to standard error is a bit of an over-kill.  The `read` utility already displays the prompt on standard error by default.

Comment: @ilkkachu The 5.1 manual, in documenting `read -p`, explicitly says that the prompt is displayed on standard error. Note that the manual you linked to was last updated in 2020.  Besides, the shell will _always_ prompt the user on the standard error stream. `select` does this too, for example.

Comment: @ilkkachu `read` has prompted the user on the standard error stream since 1996 when it first got the `-p` option.  And again, the shell will always prompt the user on standard error. This is common knowledge, or should be.

Comment: @ilkkachu The question is tagged with [tag:bash]. The shell in question is `bash`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Bash is the only shell relevant for this question though (see tags). Its `read` utility prompts on standard error, and has always done so. This is easily tested, and is documented in the manual.

Comment: @ilkkachu In the up to date manual, yes. And evident from the commit history since 1996.

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, that's clearly a bug. You may want to submit a patch or a bug report then.

Comment: I wonder: If the prompt is sent to `stderr`, what about the echo of the user's input; specifically if the user tries to edit an incorrect input.

Comment: @U.Windl That's what I wasn't sure about, and that's why I explicitly redirected to stderr.  The `help` page says: "`-s do not echo input from a terminal`" and that suggested to me it uses the same output as `echo` would.  But I see being too explicit has caused some discussion.